# Are ATC towers built in warzones?

Tags: air-traffic-control, military

Take Afghanistan as a for instance; do governments (e.g. USAF/RAF) or NATO construct ATC towers?

I'd imagine so, at the air bases, in order to land/takeoff the vast amount of aircraft.

Who controls the sectors where missions are ongoing? How are the different countries' aircraft coordinated and kept apart?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, sometimes control towers or other ATC facilities are constructed to support air traffic control. If, for example an ATC tower is needed (there was none previously or it was destroyed), a mobile replacement is used.

[image][image]

For mission control Airborne Warning and Control Systems (AWACS) are used:

[image]

But these are quite expensive to fly. If possible, mobile surface based radars are brought in to provide a surveillance picture.

Mobile towers, radars and navigation beacon are not solely used in war situations. In natural disasters they have proven to be useful as well:

[FAA sends temporary Air Traffic Control tower to Haiti](http://avstop.com/news_jan_2010/faa_sends_temporary_air_traffic_control_tower_to_haiti.htm)

[image]

Comment: See also Mobile Tower System (MOTS): [Marketing glossy (PDF)](http://www.sncorp.com/pdfs/BusinessAreas/MOTS%20Product%20Sheet%20FINAL.pdf), [SNC YouTube](http://youtu.be/sD-ju477sW4), [SNC news blurb](http://www.sncorp.com/AboutUs/NewsDetails/480)

Comment: Misread that last one for a moment as "FAA sends temporary Air Traffic Control tower to Hell".  :-P

Comment: The link for that [marketing glossy PDF](http://mediakit.sncorp.com/mediastore/document/MOTS%20Product%20Sheet%20FINAL.pdf) has changed.